# Force on a charge placed in conducting shell

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

I have a very different theoretical physics question. Suppose we place a positive charge inside a conducting shell(not at the centre and not fixed), it induces the negative charge inside the shell. Now my doubt is by symmetry, the force on the charge is zero. But as the charge induces more negative charge on the side to which it is more close than the side which is far to it(as shown in the diagram), so the side which has more negative charge density attracts it.So force is not zero. But by shell theorem as it is perfectly spherical symmetry force is zero. So which of the above is true. If any other, why?[image]

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231693/104696

Comment: @Farcher No, it's not duplicate. The question I asked is about the conducting shell. But the link you posted is non-conducting shell case. And I couldn't get any answer to my question anywhere. Even our physics teachers couldn't explain. This situation is not in books. I don't know what to do. Still searching for an answer.

Comment: The link was about a conducting shell. Read the OP’s question. The problem with your diagram is that you have too many induced negative charges near the positive charge which makes it appear that you will have a net force to the right.

Comment: @Farcher I  suggest you to read the question you posted one more time.Nothing was given about conducting nature of shell. That question can be solved by Shell theorem. But this can't be solved. It's a pretty mess question.

Comment: @Farcher although not explicit but all answers on that linked question assume that shell is non conducting and proceed to apply shell theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not perfectly symmetric so you cannot apply shell theorem here. So there is no contradiction, the positive charge will move towards the inner surface of shell due to electrostatic attraction if it is not placed at the centre of shell.